# Notification Listener Service not always working

Tags: java, android, android-service, listener, android-notifications

I'm trying to work on an app that sends notifications to my pc.
I used an `NotificationListenerService` which seems to work on an Emulator(Pixel XL API29) but when trying it on my Oneplus 7 Pro (Android 10) it only works randomly.

My Code can be found here as I want to make it open source or at least visible for others: https://github.com/MrMinemeet/PhoneConnect

**`onCreate`** in the `NotificationReceiver.class` get's called as a breakpoint will stop there.

**`onNotificationPostet`** on the other hand is randomly working and then from one minute to the other stops getting called when a new notification arrives.
There aren't any errors it just won't get called.

I tried it on the Huawei phone (Android 7 or 8) of my friend where it has the same behavior.

In my opinion it's very strange as I always grant the permissions.

I used this example project as a guideline to build my own app on:
https://github.com/Chagall/notification-listener-service-example

Hopefully someone finds out what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement the code above

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```